# Not direct/inverse proportion implies systematic error

Tags: experimental-physics, error-analysis

We were doing error-analysis and my physics teacher said:

A relationship between physical constants is either direct proportion or inverse proportion. If these are not true then there is a systematic error.

The wording may be different but I remember him saying something like this.

Does anyone (due to having more experience than me) know what this might mean? Even if it is technically wrong, I'm sure he meant something else and I want to know what he was referring to. (Yes I can ask on Monday but I don't want to wait until then.)

Thanks!

Comment: I have no idea what your teacher could have meant by that... in general it's simply not true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a trivial point of view and in line with what you say $x \propto y \iff x=k_{1}y$ for some constant $k_{1}$. On the other hand $x \propto \frac{1}{y} \iff x=\frac{k_{2}}{y}$ for some constant $k_{2}$. If none of these relationships holds, then there may well be an error in the assumptions in proportionality.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is what he meant! If it's meant to be direct proportion (going through (0,0)) but the graph isn't then there's a systematic error. But I don't see how this applies to the inverse proportion one: Inverse proportion graphs aren't meant to go through (0,0) so you can't tell from the graph if there's a systematic error.

Comment: So if two quantites are in inverse proportion then their product must equal a constant (the same constant!) $\forall$ values of $x,y$. If this is not true (incorporating rounding errors), then there is a systematic error.

Comment: And I am talking about the relation $xy=k_{2}$ for some constant $k_{2}$.